# sqlite database inserts the same value everytime error

Tags: android, sqlite, checkbox

Am displaying random checkboxes from remote server and if a user checks a checkbox then am storing that value in sqlite database and on the next loading am checking whether that value is present in database or not and if its present then bydefault it will check the checkbox. my problem is everytime i try to insert a value to sqlite it always takes the first checked checkbox value. But if I use a toast to check my code am getting the respective checkbox value. but that doesn't work with sqlite

Here is how am displaying a checkbox and setting on clicklistener

```
  rl = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.linearmain);
            HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
            sqlcon = new SQLController(context);
            sqlcon.open();
            CheckBox[] cb = new CheckBox[arraylist.size()];

            Cursor c = sqlcon.readEntry();
            int rows = c.getCount();
            int cols = c.getColumnCount();


            for(int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
                resultp = arraylist.get(i);

                cb[i] = new CheckBox(getActivity());
                cb[i].setText(resultp.get(Fltrsubfragment.SUB));
                cb[i].setId(i);
                cb[i].setOnClickListener(handleOnClick(cb[i]));
                rl.addView(cb[i]);
                for ( int ikv = 0; ikv < rows; ikv++) {

                    // inner for loop
                    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                        String iv;
                        iv=c.getString(j);

                        if(iv==null){
                            Toast.makeText(context, " Empty " + rows, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                       else if(iv.equals(cb[i].getText().toString())){
                            cb[i].setChecked(true);

                            Toast.makeText(context, " Checked " + rows, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        else{
                            cb[i].setChecked(false);

                        }

                    }
                }


   View.OnClickListener handleOnClick(final CheckBox button) {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(button.isChecked()){
                    if(barraylist.contains(button.getText().toString())){
                        Toast.makeText(context, " Already added " + button.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {

                        brandarraylist.add(button.getText().toString());
                        name=button.getText().toString();

                        new MyAsync().execute();

                        Toast.makeText(context, " Stored " + button.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                }
                else{
                    if(barraylist.contains(button.getText().toString()))
                    {

                        barraylist.remove(button.getText().toString());
                        name=button.getText().toString();

                        new MyAsyncS().execute();
                        sqlcon.deleteTData(button.getText().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Removed this " + button.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Unchecked this " + button.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

AsyncTask code to insert value

```
private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        PD = new ProgressDialog(context);
        PD.setMessage("Loading...");
        PD.setCancelable(false);
        PD.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if(name==null){
            return null;
        }
        // inserting data
        else{
            sqlcon = new SQLController(context);
            sqlcon.open();

            sqlcon.insertData(name);
            sqlcon.close();
            // BuildTable();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        PD.dismiss();
    }
}
```

here is the insertData code

```
 public void insertData(String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(MyDbHelper.LT_VAL, name);
    database.insert(MyDbHelper.LTE, null, cv);

}
```

Please suggest where am making the mistake.

Comment: try sending `name` to `MyAsync` 's constructor and initialize it in `MyAsync` again. Then use that new one inside `MyAsync`

Comment: still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Inside `new MyAsync().execute();` put `name`:

I recommend using `.trim()` on all user input. You could easily chain this to:

```
name=button.getText().toString().trim();


new MyAsync().execute(name);
```

Then get it by using:

```
  @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String name = params[0];
```

We ruled out context by changing the code to:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String ... params) {
    String name = params[0];
    if(name==null){
        return null;
    }else{
        return name;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);      
        sqlcon = new SQLController(context);
        sqlcon.open();

        sqlcon.insertData(result);
        sqlcon.close();
        // BuildTable();

    PD.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: So what value is showing up on a System.out.println(params[0])?

Comment: If you Toast the name variable before you send it to async that is a different value than the one inside of async?

Comment: weird part is it shows the respective checkbox value but adds only the first checked checkbox value .. Is there any mistake am doing in the insertData function?

Comment: Yes onPostExecute(String result), will contain a returned value from doInBackground. I just wanted you to test that in order to rule out the context being inside doInBackground causing an issue.

Comment: is there any error with sql connection open close or while inserting data?

Comment: Could you post the exact error from the log? Thanks

Comment: Error:(174, 33) error: incompatible types
required: String
found:    Void
Error:(178, 24) error: incompatible types
required: Void
found:    String

Comment: Oh my mistake, change void to String in the do in background and onPostExecute. I updated my answers, it was a typo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74757/discussion-between-asish-rauto-and-petro).

Comment: that's not working.. can you please guide me how I can prevent duplicate entries to my table by setting primary key .. this how I have created the Table.. can you help me on this.... private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table " + LTE 
+ "(" + LT_VAL + " VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY);";